How to make a 3D mountain mesh change shape in the rythm of a song?
this here is an animation made with AI tool Deforum: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Oee78kHxLDw
The frames are generated with Stable Diffusion and translations are applied between the frames. The movement of the mountains is also made happen using controlnet with an audio visualizer clip.
I'm trying to create something similar but in 3D Blender. Basically, I want to have a mesh of a mountain, and I want to have it change shape on the beat of that song. And I want to make it look as dynamic as in that AI version. I don't want to have a basic 3D mesh audio visualizer.
Here is what I have managed to make so far: https://imgur.com/a/C4sQjMx
Currently, I'm using a pretty complex method: for any movement in the mesh, I create a cube and I create a VertexWeightProximity modifier for the location that I want to change. I then animate the cube to move up so that it creates movement in the mountain.
How should I do this? I think the hardest part is making the transformations in the mesh look very dynamic (almost like fluid).
Thanks!

Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload images or gifs, along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

i would use geometry nodes for that. If you know how you can "shape" your landscape with geometry nodes, just use the "right" input nodes and use drivers of your sampled music fcurve.
